# How to plot data from two dictionaries of dataframes onto one plot in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dictionary

I have two dictionaries of dataframes that are generated from separate for loops.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Control_Keys = ('C1','C2','C3','C4')
Patient_Keys = ('P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6')

df_columns = ['Reads','Score']

C_dict = {}
P_dict = {}

# Generating dictionaries of dataframes
for i in Control_Keys:
    C_dict[i] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,2)), columns=df_columns)
    
for i in Patient_Keys:
    P_dict[i] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,2)), columns=df_columns)
```

I want to plot their data using the same axis on the same graph, where the x-axis is 'Reads' and the y-axis is 'Score'. I also want to be able to differentiate between the two groups, (not individual data) where all data belonging to Controls are blue, and Patients are red. I am able to plot these individually, but I have not been able to find a reliable way to merge these two graphs into one.

Comment: As an example, are you saying that you want to plot `C_dict['C1']` and `P_dict['P1']` on the same graph, and have data from `C_dict` be blue and `P_dict` be red?

Comment: Right, except I want all the data on the same graph and each is its own set of data. For example, I want to plot C_dict['C1'} through C_dict['C4'], which would be 4 sets of data, and P_dict['P1'] through P_dict['P6'], which would be 6, all on the same graph, resulting in 10 lines of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would slightly redesign your dataframe in order to achieve your plotting goal. I would first assign the key as a column (optionally, if you need to distinguish) and also assign the column as another property to help with color distinguishing (`hue`)

Below I combine all the C's, P's and assign two new columns: `Table` and `Hue`

```
c = pd.DataFrame()

for key in Control_Keys:
    C_dict[key]['Table'] = key
    C_dict[key]['Hue'] = 'C'
    c = c.append(C_dict[key])
    
p = pd.DataFrame()

for key in Patient_Keys:
    P_dict[key]['Table'] = key
    P_dict[key]['Hue'] = 'P'
    p = p.append(P_dict[key])
```

Then you plot them and assign `hue` parameter for color assignment and `palette` to change the color:

```
sns.scatterplot(x='Reads', y='Score', hue='Hue', data=p.append(c), palette=['Red', 'Blue'])
plt.show()
```